# The "length" name always shown in the output - R programming

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R programming language. As a function below, I return a data frame but output always shows the "length" name instead of indexes. Can somebody advice, please.

The indicates appear if it is more than 2.

My expected result is to show `1, 2, 3`

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:322){  

#set working directory
  setwd(directory) 
  
  #list all csv files in the working dir and save to listScvFile variable
  listCsvFile <- list.files(pattern = ".csv$") 
  
  #create original DataSet
  originalData <- lapply(listCsvFile[id],read.csv)
  
  #create working Dataset based on the pollutan argument 
  #and save to a vector
  workingDataSetVector <- c(length = length(id))
  
  for (i in 1:length(id)) {
    workingDataSet <- originalData[[i]][,"sulfate"]
    badWorkingDataSet <- is.na(workingDataSet)
    goodWorkingDataSet <- workingDataSet[!badWorkingDataSet]
    workingDataSetVector[i] = length(goodWorkingDataSet)
  }
  
  return(data.frame(id = id, nobs = workingDataSetVector))
}
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqksz.jpg)

Comment: CAn you please clarify what do you want? Is it that you do not want `length` to appear in the 1st case, and `1, 2, 3` in the 2nd case to the left of the first column?

Comment: Add your code by copying and pasting not images. It's easier to use copy-pastable code.

Comment: @yarnabrina my expected result is to show 1, 2, 3 indexes at all time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 workingDataSetVector <- c()
```

Instead of

```
 workingDataSetVector <- c(length = length(id))
```